# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before semicolon

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, syntax-error

hi i am new to AS3 in flash. i was trying to add a link button on my flash but i get the (1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before semicolon.) when i test it .

this is the code i created:

```
function myButtonPressed(event:MouseEvent){
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://pinoytoon.blogspot.com","_blank");
```

`}`

```
myButton.useHandCursor = true;
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myButtonPressed);
```

please help me!!!

Comment: Did you try adding a rightparen before the semi-colon? Your problem is that you've opened two brackets (parentheses) and closed only one. You need to close both.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you forgot close *navigateToURL* function with a rightparen:

```
function myButtonPressed(event:MouseEvent){
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://pinoytoon.blogspot.com","_blank"));
}

myButton.useHandCursor = true;
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myButtonPressed);
```

i hope i could help you!